# Is only Blender 2.91 for Mac so buggy

Tags: osx, versions

contrary to Blender 2.8 Blender 2.91 is very buggy. Each time my mac goes to sleep mode Blender crashes when waking up. And sometimes even my files can be loaded any more, it simply crashes. Will there be updates soon?
KR Thomas

Comment: blender should not crash, but if you are experiencing reproducible crashes then you should [report it](https://developer.blender.org/) so it can be fixed. See [here also](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: Yes. Apple dropped OpenGL support in favor of their metal engine which needs to be implemented and maintained. I'd suggest switch back to 2.83... or try any linux distro.